# using "self" in association declaration (:has_many, :has_one)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to reference a model's self in a :has_many declaration.

I have a class we will call Foo. Foo :has_many Bar. Foo has a boolean attribute called randomize that determines the order of the the Bars in the :has_many relationship. If randomize is true, then they are ordered by "RAND()" or "RANDOM()" depending on the DB. If not, they are ordered by id. I HAVE to make this declaration on the association because I am using eager loading. I am well-aware that I can define a method in Foo that returns what I want, but I need to have everything loaded at once or else 400-500 queries are run individually = bad.

```
class CreateFoo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.boolean :randomize, :default => false
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateBar < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :bars do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :foo
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # this is the line that doesn't work
  has_many :bars, :order => self.randomize ? 'RAND()' : 'id'
end
```

How do I access properties of *self* in the has_many declaration?

Things I've tried and failed:

1. creating a method of Foo that returns the correct string
2. creating a lambda function
3. crying

Is this possible?

The problem seems to be that the "self" in :has_many ISN'T of type Foo:

```
undefined method `randomize' for #<Class:0x1076fbf78>
```

is one of the errors I get. Note that its a general Class, not a Foo Object... Why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out Ryan Bates has touched on a simliar topic [here](http://media.railscasts.com/videos/215_advanced_queries_in_rails_3.mov) in a Railscast. You need to define the scope AFTER the method...

Comment: Unfortunately, that url no longer works

Answer (score 0):

self in that context is the class.

To do what you need you could try to pass a lambda.

```
class Foo < AR::Base
  has_many :bars, :order => lambda { self.randomize? ? 'RAND()' : 'id'  }
end
```

I have not tested that, but it should work.

Comment: nope. doesn't work because it tries to order by the Proc. It'll produce an error like "no column <#Proc:..> in foos"

Answer (score -1):

Try using default scope instead of in the has_many declaration

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope lambda { order(self.randomize ? 'RAND()' : 'id') }
```

But to answer your question directly, the self in your has_many declaration refers to the Foo class, not an instance of Foo.

Comment: because I get - undefined method `includes_values' for #<Proc:0x1032fa630>

Comment: so how do I get the instance of Foo and not the Foo class?

Comment: Session contains objects whose class definition isn't available.
Remember to require the classes for all objects kept in the session.
(Original exception: undefined method `includes_values' for #<Proc:0x1070b7b30> [NoMethodError])