# Ruby/Rails - Why does self in association condition depend on time of creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am trying to use `self` in an association condition. I can't simply use `self` though because then it will access the actual class instead of the instance (like in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564444/using-self-in-association-declaration-has-many-has-one)). So I have a class with an association that looked like this:

```
# l.rb on Friday before the changes
has_many :t_l_relationships, :inverse_of => :l, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :ts, {
  through: :t_l_relationships,
  dependent: :destroy
}
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ts
```

After the edit, the has_many :current_ts association was added, and that is it:

```
# l.rb after the changes
has_many :t_l_relationships, :inverse_of => :l, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :ts, {
  through: :t_l_relationships,
  dependent: :destroy
}
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ts
has_many :current_tenants, {
  source: :tenant,
  through: :tenant_lease_relationships,
  conditions: proc { "tenant_lease_relationships.tenant_role_id != #{self}" }
}
```

The `self` in l.rb for accounts/l's created before the change always evaluates to an instance of l. The `self` in l.rb for accounts/l's after teh change always evaluates instead to something like: `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::JoinDependency::JoinAssociation:0x00000011f24fe8>`. It is an association instead of an instance of l. Why is this happening?

Does anyone know what may be causing this? Or another way to access the instance of the class (like self in the methods) in the association condition?

I am using Rails 3.2.11.

Answer (score 0):

always remember that proc captures the current scope(including self and local variable bindings ) of the object where it is defined.use [lambda](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope) instead

Comment: Lambda does the same. At first I get an error saying that I have 0 arguments when I need one. So I added a dummy argument: `lambda { |l| " #{self} " }`, but I still get that `self` is an `ActiveRecord::Associations::JoinDependency::JoinAssociation`. But only in accounts created after Friday. Every account created before Friday works with both proc and lambda.

Comment: @Isaac can you show the the accounts created before and after friday..i guess you might be missing some asociation/dependency .

Comment: OK, so I've dramatically changed the question. I think this better explains my issue. I've left out the other model now, `e.rb`, that is working appropriately and am now just comparing `l.rb` before and after the changes and which accounts/l's work and which don't.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just realized you asked for the accounts, the accounts haven't been changed at all. They are generated the exact same way as before, the only difference now is that l.rb has been changed.

Comment: My issue was in the filtering system we have set up. I've got it it working correctly now. Thanks for the help though!